# BibTex - Show ISBN number?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

Is it possible to show the ISBN/ISSN fields of books with BibTeX? For instance, I have the following entry on my .bib file:

```
@book{QueueSystems,
    author    = "Leonard Kleinrock",
    title     = "Queueing Systems. Volume 1: Theory",
    publisher = "Wiley-Interscience",
    year      = "1975",
    ISBN      = "0471491101"
}
```

With "plain" style, it's printed like this:

```
[11] Leonard Kleinrock. Queueing Systems. Volume 1: Theory. Wiley-Interscience, 1975.
```

I've tried several different styles with no success, and I can't seem to find any answer on this site or through Google...

Comment: Output from BibTeX depends on the style you use. Perhaps the easiest solution here is to switch to `biblatex`.

Comment: You note that "I've tried several different styles with no success". Did you try using `plainnat.bst`, `unsrtnat.bst`, and/or `IEEEtran.bst`? All three of these styles, among quite a few others, should have no problems typesetting the ISBN/ISSN fields of an entry.

Comment: I tried all the styles that came with the default installation of MikTeX. I also tried to install some additional styles, but I couldn't really figure out how to. Either way, `biblatex` seems to provide what I was looking for...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is very easy with [`biblatex`](http://Ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) (at least as long one takes care of closing commas in `.bib` files):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{QueueSystems,
    author    = "Leonard Kleinrock",
    maintitle     = "Queueing Systems",
    volume     = "1",     
    title     = "Theory",
    publisher = "Wiley-Interscience",
    year      = "1975",
    ISBN      = "0471491101",
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

For more information about "first steps" with `biblatex` see [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex)

Answer (score 12):

Under the conditions

- You don't want to switch to biblatex,
- You don't want to change your
  .bst,

you can always put the ISBN (or anything else) in a note:

```
@book{lic,
  [...],
  note={{ISBN:} 978-91-637-4473-0}
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You write

> Is it possible to show the ISBN/ISSN fields of books with BibTeX? ... I've tried several different styles with no success...

The answer is "Yes." However, in order to achieve your goal you need to use a bibliography style file that's of more recent vintage than `plain.bst`. The `plain` style file, which is more than twenty years old by now, is not set to recognize fields such as `url`, `isbn`, `issn`, and `doi`. Fortunately, a lot of the newer style files -- such as `plainnat`, `unsrtnat`, and `IEEEtran` -- *do* know how to process these fields.

For instance, with the `plainnat` style file and the `natbib` package loaded, the reference in question would be printed as follows:

[image]

Comment: not working for me

Comment: @mindstorm - "not working for me" is rather nonspecific. Please state what it is that's not working. Which bibliography style do you use? Do you get error and/or warning messages? Please don't expect me to simply "know" the answers to these questions; in fact, I'm probably the world's worst mind reader...

Comment: Sorry for that. I dont get any error. I've tried to use `plainnat`, `unsrtnat`, and `IEEEtran` in `\bibliographystyle{}`, not any of them show `ISBN={12345}` which is defined inside my `.bib` file.
I use `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}` and `\usepackage[english]{babel}`.

Comment: @mindstorm - After saving the bib file (with at least one entry that contains a field named `isbn`, right?) and changing the argument of `\bibliographystyle` (to `plainnat`, say), did you run a full recompile cycle: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX *twice more*?

Comment: Yes you are right and yes I did and I've just noticed that it works if I specify ISBN for `@book` but not for `@article` which is I guess desired behaviour `:^)`

Comment: @mindstorm - Do articles published in journals *ever* have an ISBN? I thought the "B" in "ISBN" stands for "book" -- unless, of course, the acronym refers to the Indiana State Board of Nursing... :-)

Answer (score 1):

For me worked this solution.

You will actually have to go to the citation style you are using, e.g. I am using *IEEEtran.bst*. You will find it in your texlive install dir. Make a copy and name it e.g. *my_IEEE.bst*.

Go to : https://people.kth.se/~maguire/myIEEEtran.bst

You will have to include these lines of the code, that are marked by the author as *%% GQMJr*, into your *my_IEEE.bst*.

Then copy your altered file *my_IEEE.bst* into your working directory (where you are going to compile your latex file). And don't forget to include:

\bibliographystyle{my_IEEEtran.bst}

Try to compile, it should work.

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem in year 2021. I am using BibTeX.

I failed to solve this problem using the answers above (My bad~).

Then I googled out a perfect solution:
https://www.bibtex.com/f/isbn-field/

Bascially speaking, is to change the style of your Bib. There are only few Bib-styles that can understand ISBN. These styles are all listed in the website linked above.

Since I need to use ISBN, ISSN and DOI, so I have redefined my bib style as:

`\bibliographystyle{unsrtnm}`

Then every thing goes fine.

Just in case:

1. Don't forget to delete all your `.aux .log .out .pdf .toc .idx .nlo .bbl .blg` files, before your changing/adding the `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnm}` to your `.tex` file.

--> After deleting all the pre-set/useless/will-be-generated-again-automatically files. Then you can rebuild your PDF output, with the newly defined bib-style.

2. Try to use only one bib-style

--> Please try to avoid double use of `\bibliographystyle{xxxx}`

--> Using "crtl+F" to ensure that "there is no other `\bibliographystyle{xxxx}`defined somewhere else in your tex file.

Hope it helps~

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Pretty awkward reading in 2022 that ISBN is loosely supported as if it's something unusual, from alien planet (available since the 60s btw.)

Comment: The key really is to delete log-files as mentioned. Otherwise changes are not reflected in the output. (I have a slightly other situation to deal with, but it was a good reminder)