# Showing ISBN using IEEEtran.bst

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran

I saw [BibTex - Show ISBN number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52040/15395) where it says that `IEEEtran.bst` will show the ISBN data. I am using this in my thesis, but it does not show the ISBN data. Can you suggest what could be wrong or what changes are required?

Comment: If you are not close to finishing it switch to BibLaTeX. You won't regret it.

Comment: I am almost done and thesis is long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Mico was wrong on this one. None of the IEEE* styles recognizes the ISBN entry. You could either switch to another style that has support for this, or hack `IEEEtran.bst` to achieve it, or switch to `biblatex` altogether.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be solved using a small trick. In `ieeetran` style, when you use `@book`, don't use ISBN field, you may use other field to insert ISBN, I am using "note" field like that:

```
note = {ISBN: 978-1111111111}
```

, or any format you like. May this trick solve your issue.

Comment: using `note` it prints the first letter of "ISBN" small as "iSBN: 978-1111111111".