# Biblatex not showing ISBN with apa style

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I have taken this example from [BibTex - Show ISBN number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52040/bibtex-show-isbn-number):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}  %% added in a recent edit
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{QueueSystems,
    author    = "Leonard Kleinrock",
    maintitle = "Queueing Systems",
    volume    = "1",     
    title     = "Theory",
    publisher = "Wiley-Interscience",
    year      = "1975",
    ISBN      = "0471491101",
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

which works well as long as I do not specify the apa format. If I add the `style=apa` after `backend=biber`, it stops showing the ISBN entry.
what should I do to make this example show the ISBN ?
I tested adding `\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}` but to no avail. My installation of biblatex is very recent (version 3.3) and biber is version 2.4.

Comment: As per the package docs, add a `babel` line before loading biblatex - `\usepackage[american]{babel}`

Comment: True, adding `\usepackage[american]{babel}` allowed the document to compile. However, I still don't see the ISBN. Looking in the .bbl file, I do see the isbn fields `\field{isbn}{0471491101}`. So it does not completely answer the problem. Would it be possible that the apa format is outdated? the file `american-apa.lbx` is date 2016/03/01...

Comment: You have two unrelated problems here. The first one is the standard "you are missing \DeclareLanguageMapping" error, the second is that you don't get to see the ISBN. Since you are aware of the `\DeclareLanguageMapping` issue yourself, maybe you want to clean up your question to drop this, it is a red herring, but seems to have confused people trying to answer.

Comment: References for the `\mkbibdateapalongextra` issue are [problems using apa6e with biblatex-apa](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36331/35864), [Problem with \mkbibdateapalongextra of biblatex-apa](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/133700/35864) and [Can't define apa as bibstyle “Undefined control sequence. <argument> \mkbibdateapalongextra”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/296476/35864).

Comment: Showing ISBN is not part of APA style, that's why it's not implemented.

Comment: In the earlier version of the question, I had forgotten the package babel call, my mistake. The answer from @PLK is in fact the correct answer. My bad: I was with the impression that ISBN should be visible as part of the APA style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see `biblatex-apa` just doesn't print the ISBN (from that I would infer that APA style does not require the inclusion of ISBNs - indeed, [PLK confirms this in his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302523/biblatex-not-showing-isbn-with-apa-style#comment733384_302523)). If you must have ISBNs you can modify the `doi+eprint+url`

```
\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
  \printfield{isbn}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
    {\printfield{doi}%
     \iffieldundef{doi}{}{\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\relax}}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}%
     \iffieldundef{eprint}{}{\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\relax}}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:url}
    {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}%
     \iffieldundef{url}{}{\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\relax}}}
    {}}
```

With this change you could forfeit APA compliance, so make sure you really need to show the ISBN.

Comment: Thanks @moewe for setting the record straigth: APA indeed does not show ISBN. My mistake here. Thanks also for this answer and the note of caution: If one really wants to show ISBN, it shows how it can be done.

Comment: Note that currently (2021) the macro to change is `doi+url`, so without `eprint`. But the ISBN is still not part of the APA recommendations.

Comment: **@moewe**: I'm also using APA style with biblatex and I would be interested in slightly customising the style. Specifically, I would like to have all non-empty fields in my .bib file printed. For journal articles that is already the case by default, but for books, proceedings, book collections, etc., I would also like to have ISBN, location, publisher, etc. fields printed, regardless of whether there is an available DOI or not. Which macros have to be modified so that those fields are not supressed and how precisely?

Comment: @Euclides `biblatex-apa` implements APA style (as defined in the publication manual of the APA) as closely as possible with `biblatex`. It is not really intended for (large-scale and even smaller scale) modifications. If you want/need APA style, use `biblatex-apa`. If you don't want APA style, do yourself a favour and use a different base style (e.g. `authoryear`).

Comment: **@moewe**: I understand that, but I am not the only one not fully satisfied with the APA style. Even Elsevier modified it: for instance, they use location-publisher for books, etc. and dropped the journal article issue from their own APA style. As this would be for my PhD thesis and there are no strict guidelines at University level, I thought customisation would be OK for this case. Anyway if one can modify the `doi+url` bibmacro, there is certainly a way to modify the `location+publisher` bibmacro as well. I will try to find out..............

Comment: @Euclides Well, it is not that it is scientifically or aesthetically a bad idea to modify APA style (though I personally am not too fond of the fact that everyone seems to want to modify existing styles), it is just pretty painful to modify `biblatex-apa` because it was written specifically to make exactly what the APA wants and was not written with customisability in mind. A standard style like `authoryear` is much, much easier to customise.

Comment: **@moewe**: I am open to that (the easier to code the modifications in question, the better), but I don't have a lot of time. How can I then modify the `authoryear` style (or some other `authoryear` style variant like perhaps `ext-authoryear`, which could from the start be even closer to the `apa` style), so that it reflects the `apa` style, but with my own specific needs for books, proceedings, etc. (i.e., ISBN, location, publisher, date, etc. fields appearing)? Should I open a speficic question for that purpose?

Comment: **@moewe**: meanwhile, I found a solution for printing the ISBN field by using the `xpatch` package and adding this line to the preamble: `\xpretobibmacro{doi+url}{\printfield{isbn}}{}{}`. Not sure if I can replicate the same to print the location field of the `location+publisher` bibmacro, and then later other fields like date, venue, series, or volume, as soon as I find out in which bibmacros they are stored..............

Comment: @Euclides Yes, if you need help with a specific endeavour, please open a new question (with code example what you have so far as well as a clear explanation of the output you want). The comments are not really the right place to discuss problems that go far beyond what was asked in the original question. Especially in this case where the discussion would have to involve longer code blocks and explanations.

Answer (score 0):

I do not get an error. I am using latest Debian. I copied and pasted your code into Texstudio, and viewed pdf, showing the citation with ISBN number.

I added the style=apa so that:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
```

and still no error.

Comment: Hum... I use MiKTeX version 2.9.

Comment: Are you sure you are still seeing the ISBN with `style=apa`? I have the current version (2016/03/01 v6.8) and don't get to see the ISBN.

Comment: Have rerun, still seeing the ISBN.

Texstudio is 2,10,8
Biblatex is 3.3, dated March 8 2016

Comment: What is your `biblatex-apa` version though? As I said I don't get the ISBN with `style=apa` and PLK (the developer) confirms this behaviour in his comments above.

Answer (score 0):

The values are to be given within braces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{QS:1,
author    = {Leonard Kleinrock},
maintitle = {Queueing Systems},
volume    = {1}, 
title     = {Theory},
publisher = {Wiley-Interscience},
year      = {1975},
isbn     = {0471491101},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: bibi]

Comment: Although I do prefer to wrap fields in braces and not in quotation marks you will find that you example still works if you use `"` instead of `{...}`. The issue here is the `biblatex-apa` style and not the field delimiters. `"` and `{...}` are largely equivalent ...