# Why are my notes not showing while using apa style with biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

So I'm still working on this big essay and today I noticed that the notes we added in the .bib file are not showing up in the bibliography. It is only happening when I'm using the apa style. Maybe printing the note data field is not implemented, just like the ISBN? ([Biblatex not showing ISBN with apa style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302523/biblatex-not-showing-isbn-with-apa-style#comment733384_302523)) Otherwise, what am I doing wrong?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,citestyle=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}
\addbibresource{sources.bib}

\begin{document}
Content. \parencite{something_one} More content \parencite{something-else_one} more content.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And the sources.bib file:

```
@online{something_one,
author      =   {Some One},
title       =   {Something},
year        =   {nodate},
url         =   {https://somesite.org/somepage},
urldate     =   {2017-12-19},
note        =   {I'm a note}
}

@online{something-else_one,
author      =   {Some One},
title       =   {Something else},
year        =   {nodate},
url         =   {https://somesite.org/someotherpage},
urldate     =   {2017-12-19},
note        =   {I'm another note}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se, and thanks for posting a minimal example document. The bibliography driver for `online` elements isn't set up to print the note. What are you using the note field for, exactly?

Comment: Multiple uses, but for example, I'm citing from Wikipedia and I would like to have the date of last revision in the bibliography.

Comment: Ok. For that you should use the `urldate` field. See §4.2.2 of the `biblatex-apa` documentation.

Comment: I notice that the `@online` entry type supports the `addendum` field. In contrast to the `note` field, the `addendum` field prints after the `url` and `urdate`. But perhaps it would suit you.

Comment: @AlanMunn isn't `urldate` used for "retrieved on"? APA§4.2.2 actually also says so. What if you want both "Retrieved on: <date>" and "Published on/Last updated on: <date>" (obtainable from the website infos)?

Comment: @AlanMunn The urldate is indeed used for the date I checked out the webpage. Apart from that I also want to note the date when then the last change to the wikipage was made.

Comment: @DavidPurton Thank you! I think I'm going to use this, but I'm sure there must be some way to get the "note" data field to work as well. If I find something I will post it here.

Comment: Bassie-c: @DavidPurton is correct that the `addendum` can be used. Where in the entry would the "Last Updated on" information go relative to other elements in the reference? I don't have the actual APA guide to find out.  If it's where the `addendum` should go, then you're not gaining much with making a version for using the `note` field.

Comment: It is possible to patch the @online output to include the `note` field. It just depends on the APA guidelines where things should go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the comments above, this is how to patch the `@online` entry type driver to include the `note` field.

1. Have a look in the file `apa.bbx` and find the `online` driver (search for `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{online}`).
2. Have a look through this driver and see where you want to put the `note` field. Most drivers put the `note` field before any `doi` or `url`.
3. You'll see that immediately before the `doi` field there is `\printfield{entrysubtype}`.
4. We can patch the driver using `xpatch` to insert the `note` field after this with a period and space in between like this:

   ```
   \usepackage{xpatch}% load the xpatch package
   \xpatchbibdriver{online}% patch the online driver:
     {\printfield{entrysubtype}}% replace this line
     {\printfield{entrysubtype}%  with these lines
      \newunit\newblock
      \printfield{note}}
     {}
     {}
   ```

## Full MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{something_one,
  author  = {Some One},
  title   = {Something},
  year    = {nodate},
  url     = {https://somesite.org/somepage},
  urldate = {2017-12-19},
  note    = {I'm a note}
}
@online{something-else_one,
  author  = {Some One},
  title   = {Something else},
  year    = {nodate},
  url     = {https://somesite.org/someotherpage},
  urldate = {2017-12-19},
  note    = {I'm another note}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{online}
  {\printfield{entrysubtype}}
  {\printfield{entrysubtype}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \printfield{note}}
  {}
  {}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]