# ISBN with APA Style

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I want to use the APA style for my thesis but at my university, ISBN numbers are required. Now I probably need to change the bibliography style manually to include the ISBN. I've tried [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/302576) but that did not work either. Does anyone have another way around the standard APA style in order to add the ISBN?

Note: APA Plain-Style works fine, also added the ISBNs to .bib file

**Edit with relevant information:**

Example Document:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,toc=bibliography]{srcreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,citestyle=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\addbibresource{bibliographie.bib}
\begin{document}
    Here is some text with some quotes.\autocite[12]{Jazar2010}

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Example bibliography.bib

```
@book{Jazar2010,
    author = "Jazar, Reza",
    title = "Theory of Applied Robotics",
    edition = "2",
    publisher = "Springer",
    year = "2010",
    isbn = "978-1-4419-1749-2"
}
```

What the current bibliography looks like:

*Jazar, R. (2010). Theory of Applied Robotics (2nd ed.). Springer.*

What it should look like:

*Jazar, R. (2010). Theory of Applied Robotics (2nd ed.). Springer. ISBN: 978-3-658-24821-5.* or
*Jazar, R. (2010). Theory of Applied Robotics (2nd ed.). Springer. 978-3-658-24821-5.*

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Currently your question is a bit unclear. How do you create your bibliography? With BibTeX or BibLaTeX? Which style do you use exactly? What do you want the output to be? It would be helpful to add a small example document to your question that shows your setup, with the relevant documentclass, packages and settings and a bit of content that has one or two citations. The rest of the document should be minimized, i.e., all packages and content that is not related to citations should be removed. Use the `edit` button below the post to add the example.

Comment: @Marijn I added the relevant information, hope the scope is a bit more clear now.

Comment: the macro name from the duplicate has changed, you now need `\renewbibmacro*{doi+url}` (instead of `doi+eprint+url`). The rest of the answer works unmodified.

Comment: @Marijn Thanks, that helped as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is equivalent to the one given here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/302576/231952 (with `doi+url` instead of `doi+eprint+url`, as suggested by Marijn), but the result is obtained via `xpatch` which saves a few lines of code:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
  \xpretobibmacro{doi+url}{\printfield{isbn}}{}{}
```

This simply prepend to the `doi+url` the command `\printfield{isbn}`.

**MWE**

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{Jazar2010,
 author = "Jazar, Reza",
 title = "Theory of Applied Robotics",
 edition = "2",
 publisher = "Springer",
 year = "2010",
 isbn = "978-1-4419-1749-2"
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[oneside,12pt,toc=bibliography]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,citestyle=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{xpatch}
  \xpretobibmacro{doi+url}{\printfield{isbn}}{}{}

\begin{document}
 Here is some text with some quotes.\autocite[12]{Jazar2010}
 
 \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, that solution worked for me. The equivalent one without xpatch did not work though.

Comment: In the equivalent one you have to replace `doi+eprint+url` with `doi+url`